# Computation of second derivatives with batch_jacobian in tensorflow is really slow during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.x

I am trying to compute the Hessian of the output of a neural network with respect to its inputs. To give you an idea, this is the matrix I am trying to compute:

[image]

I am running Tensorflow 2.5.0 and my code to calculate the M matrix looks like this:

```
def get_Mass_Matrix(self, q, dq):
    nDof = dq.shape[1]
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent = True) as t2:
        t2.watch(dq)
        with tf.GradientTape(persistent = True) as t1:
            t1.watch(dq)
            T = self.kinetic(q, dq)
            
        g = t1.gradient(T, dq)
    h = t2.batch_jacobian(g, dq)
        
    return h
```

The function *self.kinetic()* calls a multilayer perceptron. When I compute *M* like this, I get the correct answer but my neural network training slows down significantly, even when running on a GPU.

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to perform the same computation that doesn't result in so much overhead? Thank you.

For reference, I am using the subclassing approach to build the model (it inherits from tf.keras.Model).

Edit:

Adding more details about the self.kinetic function:

```
def kinetic(self, q, qdot):
    nDof = q.shape[1]
    qdq = tf.concat([tf.reshape(q, ((-1, nDof))),
                      tf.reshape(qdot, ((-1, nDof)))], axis = -1)
    
    return self.T_layers(qdq)
```

T_layers is defined as:

```
    self.T_layers = L(nlayers = 4, n = 8, input_dim = (latent_dim, 1), nlact = 'swish', oact = 'linear')
```

Which is calling:

```
class L(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, nlayers, n, nlact, input_dim, oact = 'linear'):

        super(L, self).__init__()

        self.layers = nlayers
        self.dense_in = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n, activation = nlact, input_shape = input_dim)
        self.dense_lays = []

        for lay in range(nlayers):
            self.dense_lays.append(tf.keras.layers.Dense(n, activation = nlact, kernel_regularizer = 'l1'))

        self.dense_out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = oact, use_bias = False)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.dense_in(inputs)
        for lay in range(self.layers):
            x = self.dense_lays[lay](x)

        return self.dense_out(x)
```

I suspect part of the problem might be that I am not "building" the layers? Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Did you wrap your `get_Mass_Matrix()` by `tf.function`? Please also provide the codes for `self.kinetic()`.

Comment: I added more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get a reasonable performance from tensorflow, especially when computing gradients, you have to decorate your `get_Mass_Matrix` with `@tf.function` to make sure it runs in graph mode. To do this, everything inside the function have to be graph-mode compatible.

In the `call` function of `class L`, it is better to iterate the list directly instead of indexing it, i.e.:

```
class L(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    ...
    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.dense_in(inputs)
        for l in self.dense_lays:
            x = l(x)

        return self.dense_out(x)
```

Then, you can decorate your `get_Mass_Matrix`.

```
@tf.function
def get_Mass_Matrix(self, q, dq):
    with tf.GradientTape() as t2:
        t2.watch(dq)
        with tf.GradientTape() as t1:
            t1.watch(dq)
            T = self.kinetic(q, dq)    
        g = t1.gradient(T, dq)
    return t2.batch_jacobian(g, dq)
```

Remark: `q` and `dq` that are passed into `get_Mass_Matrix` must be **tensors** of **constant** shape(constant between calls), otherwise, it will retrace every time there is a new shape and slow down instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! By constant shape, I assume you don't mean the batch_size as well? Also, is there a way to tell if my model is retracing? I remember seeing some warnings in TF 2.1 but I haven't seen any warnings lately. Thanks!

Comment: I mean for the batch size as well. For example, if you use batch size 64 and then use batch size 128, it will create two graphs for shape 64 and shape 128 respectively. Then afterwards, as long as you keep using these two shapes, it will not retrace because it keeps both graphs in memory.(i.e. it will take slightly more memory) To prevent it from retracing, you only need to pay attention to the shapes and types of arguments input to the function. It will also automatically print warning messages if a graph is retraced ~ 5 times consecutively.

Comment: For details, see https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function